# How to disable the tooltips on a Google Gantt Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is there a way to disable the tooltips of a Google **Gantt Chart**?

The options settings I found as possible solutions don't seem to have an effect with a Gantt Chart

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']})

...

chart.draw(data, {   
  tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
  enableInteractivity: false
});
```

or the 'workaround' via

```js
chart.draw(data, {   
  tooltip: { isHtml: true }
});
```

```css
div.google-visualization-tooltip { display:none }
```

neither works

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't need any user interaction with the chart I helped myself by simply disabling the pointer events on the chart container div

```css
   #chart_div {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

but there might be a better way via the chart settings..?!